# No way to specify a port in Flask

Tags: python, flask

In the documenation of Flask v2.2

```
Either identify and stop the other program, or use flask run --port 5001 to pick a different port.
```

Then

```
$ flask --app my_web.py --port 8021 run
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --port
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Are you actually using Flask 2.2? Did you look at `flask --help`?

Comment: Also notice the docs say... `flask run` .. **then** `--port x` (and `--app ...`)

Comment: @OneCricketeer how can it be that the order of the commands matter?

Comment: See `Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]`. So, `run` is a `command`. `--port X` is an `ARG` to `run` command... And `--app X` is an `OPTION` to `flask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the port for DEV by doing the following

```
flask --app app.py run --port 8021
```

If you're deploying to production, use Gunicorn (using flask directly to deploy to production is not recommended because it is not stable and wasn't designed for prod).  This is what using a different port in prod would look like:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

Then I would run this in the terminal

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8021  app:app
```